# Are there any advantages using maps instead of records to hold state in Erlang processes?

Tags: erlang

Most of the books or online resources I've seen are all using records to hold the state of a process (probably because that was the way for more(?) than a decade). On the other hand, maps are effectively used to replace tuples in stdlib (for example [childspecs in the supervisor module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html)).

As an example, I am working my way through [Learn You Some Erlang's Finite State Machines](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/finite-state-machines) chapter and the `state` record could be replaced with a map, declared in the `init/1` callback needed by `gen_fsm`.

- The record declaration won't be needed and most of what I've read so far, a best practice is to keep them local anyway as `.hrl` files make it harder to track errors.
- Referring to the process state in function clauses would also be shorter but they both clearly convey the structure of the state variable and a couple extra characters are not a concern.

**Also, would it be more efficient?**
I know that a well-thought out benchmark would answer my question but I am only a couple weeks into learning Erlang and the [maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106543/illegal-pattern-in-map-of-erlang) [module](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0043.html) is fairly new and still [changing](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-bugs/2014-March/004238.html).

UPDATE: Thanks to I GIVE TERRIBLE ADVICE, I read the [LYSE chapter on maps](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/maps) more thoroughly and the answer is clear:

> Using records has the advantage that the keys are known at compile
>   time that brings advantages of
>
> - fast access to specific values (faster than what is possible dynamically)
> - additional safety (crash early rather than corrupting state)
> - easier type checking
>
> **These make records absolutely appropriate for a process' internal state**, despite the occasional burden of writing a more verbose
>   code_change function.
>
> On the other hand, where Erlang users would use records to represent
>   complex nested key/value data structures (oddly similar to objects in
>   object-oriented languages) that would frequently cross module
>   boundaries, maps will help a lot. Records were the wrong tool for that
>   job.

Comment: using maps for supervisor child specs also allowed them to provide defaults when keys are not provided, e.g. restart; which can reduce the amount of boilerplate required

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've added a chapter to the *Learn You Some Erlang* website about maps specifically: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/maps

The *Mexican Standoff* section specifically compares maps to records and dicts. Semantically speaking, maps are more similar to dicts than records, and my recommendation would really be to use records where records made sense (restricted set of keys with known types with O(1) access), and maps where you'd have used dicts (heterogenous, flexible sets of key/value pairs).

Comment: Thanks, I just skimmed this chapter before, but the answer is clearly in there. I haven't read Richard O'Keefe's frame proposal yet but all the sources say it's excellent even if it is not going to be included (yet?) in Erlang/OTP.

Answer (score 1):

As Joe Armstrong [said](https://joearms.github.io/#2014-02-01%20Big%20changes%20to%20Erlang):

> Records are dead - long live maps !

and

> We’ve been talking about maps for over twelve years, but now they are
> here to stay.
>
> Why the long wait? - we wanted maps to be a replacement for records
> and to be as efficient as records, and its not blindingly obvious how
> to do so.

So, looks like the maps is ok, we have switched our project from records to maps and we have not feel not any loss of performance.

One restriction:
if I am right, you can't store maps in mnesia as you can do it with records.

Comment: What are you using maps for in your project if I may ask?

Comment: Maps are still sort of a specific use-case within my code. For most things the *semantics* of a record/tuple is appropriate -- because the data has a specific shape and the *shape is not dynamic*. This is a form of strong typing argument. Being able to check whether the shape of the data is correct can help you crash early instead of blindly plowing through some bad data in map-form for a while, perhaps making destructive updates to some external resource in the process, before realizing that this wasn't the map you thought it was (oops!).

Comment: We using maps as states in gen_server processes and in some places as source/result of decoding/encoding json