# Illegal pattern when using maps

Tags: erlang

My question is related to an existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106543/illegal-pattern-in-map-of-erlang) (and boy, was I surprised to see it was a known bug in Erlang itself!). I'm using the same `count_characters` example from the book, and getting the same error even though I'm on R19.

Code:

```
% Frequency count of characters in a string
count_characters(Str) ->
    count_characters(Str, #{}).

count_characters([H|T], #{ H => N }=X) ->
    count_characters(T, X#{ H := N+1 });
count_characters([H|T], X) ->
    count_characters(T, X#{ H => 1 });
count_characters([], X) -> X.
```

and the error:

```
1> c(lib_misc).
lib_misc.erl:40: illegal pattern
lib_misc.erl:41: variable 'N' is unbound
error
```

Here line 40 refers to the first clause of `count-characters/2`.

My questions are:

- I'm not able to understand what exactly the bug is from the linked SO question. Can someone please describe in simple terms which variable is causing the error and why?
- Is this still not fixed in R19?? If not, when will it be? It's sad to see the author's book providing an example that is so badly broken.

I can see the accepted answer on the linked page uses stuff like `maps:update`. I could do the same, but I'd first like to know why the error exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current error you see doesn't come from an Erlang bug. `=>` is used for constructing maps, `:=` for pattern matching (both are allowed for updating, the difference is that `:=` only works for keys already in the map and `=>` allows adding new keys). So you need `:=` in the pattern:

```
count_characters([H|T], #{ H := N }=X) ->
    % H => N+1 is also legal here, and means the same because we know H is a key of X
    count_characters(T, X#{ H := N+1 });
```

However, after you fix this you do run into the problem: `H` isn't bound yet in the `#{ H := N }` pattern, and this isn't currently supported. This could be fixed by matching multiple argument patterns in order, so that `H` gets bound by `[H|T]`. This isn't done in R19B (at least, judging from this example) and I don't know if there are any plans to change this. It makes sense to me personally that the patterns are checked simultaneously, so I am not even sure this change would be desirable.

You can work around this by combining the first two clauses and matching `X` in the body instead of the head:

```
count_characters([H|T], X) ->
    case X of 
        #{ H := N } -> count_characters(T, X#{ H => N+1 });
        _ -> count_characters(T, X#{ H => 1 })
    end;
count_characters([], X) -> X.
```

Comment: Ummm . . . Isn't `:=` used for updating the keys in a map and using them for another map? Sounds more like construction than pattern matching to me (or maybe not, but certainly there is construction involved).

Comment: And regarding `H` not being bound in `#{ H := N }`, the second edition of the book notes specifically: "In the first clause, the variable H inside
the map is also defined outside the map and thus is bound (as required)". Seriously, all this confusion is quite demoralizing. :(

Comment: Updating maps allows both `=>` and `:=` (the difference is that `:=` only works for keys already in the map, `=>` allows adding new keys). But `=>` can't be used in patterns. I fixed the answer's wording a bit.

Comment: Thanks. So my conclusion is there was a type in the book, where `=>` and `:=` seem to have swapped places. But beyond that, I'm very bitter about the author's (mistaken) confidence in bound variables while matching maps.

Comment: For the second the question is whether patterns for multiple arguments are matched simultaneously or left-to-right. It isn't specified in Erlang's reference manual, and I can't think of any other case where it would matter.